# bash awk how to exclude entries which contain the word 'Mouse'

Tags: linux, bash, awk

The following bash command collects the xinput id's of all devices with a name that includes ILITEK ILITEK-TP.

```
name='ILITEK ILITEK-TP'
ids=$(xinput --list |awk -Fid= "/$name/"'{print $2+0}')
```

This script works. However, I would like to exclude entries like `ILITEK ILITEK-TP Mouse` from this numerical list of ids. Currently both `ILITEK ILITEK-TP` and `ILITEK ILITEK-TP Mouse` entries are being collected into `ids`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but have you considered the `--name-only` and `--id-only` flags of `xinput --list`? You could use `xinput --list --name-only` to get a line-delimited list of inputs, filter them with grep, and then do `xinput --list --id-only $INPUT` for each input ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of

```
awk -Fid= "/$name/"'{print $2+0}'
```

is a common error.

You need:

```
awk -F'id=' -v name="$name" '$0 ~ name{print $2+0}'
```

But better use `grep` here:

```
name='ILITEK ILITEK-TP'
xinput --list | grep -oP "${name}.*?id=\K\d+"
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `${name}` | variable name |
| `.*?` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `id=` | 'id=' |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions) and [Support of \K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: That works on the commandline, but if I try to assign the output of xinput to a bash variable I get the error `awk: fatal: Cannot open file ``$0 ~ name{print $2+0}' for reading: no such file or directory`

Comment: https://hastebin.com/

Comment: https://hastebin.com/share/ufezutelec.bash

Comment: Please, clean comments

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `grep`:

```
xinput --list |grep 'ILITEK ILITEK-TP'|grep -v 'ILITEK ILITEK-TP Mouse'
```

Comment: That is a good idea however I need to extract only the numerical id from the xinput results, not the entire row.

Answer (score -1):

awk has booleans.  So you should be able to just make a little tweak:

```
name='ILITEK ILITEK-TP'
ids=$(xinput --list |awk -Fid= "/$name/"' && !/Mouse/{print $2+0}')
```

If that doesn't help, please provide some sample lines of your xinput --list output.

(edited because the quoting didn't look right.)

Comment: Don't let shell variables expand to become part of the awk script or it'll lead to cryptic errors - see [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)